# Is this a FreeBSD Handbook deficiency?

Tags: discussion, support

I find the FreeBSD Handbook approach very effective. IMO it is comprehensive, seems to be exhaustive, and yet brief.

However, I found that when I last night tried to install a desktop environment; xkfc. I have followed the instructions in the handbook for this, also tried the one alternative way described in the handbook for this. But I could not get an xkfc desktop for my freeBSD 10.3.  "not found" error when I type the `startx` command as instructed in the handbook.

Should I ask this on the main site -- is that on topic?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I don't see why not. BSDs are Unices and all Unix systems are on topic on Unix & Linux.

Go for it.